# Compare nested objects and add missing elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

Have 2 or more nested objects with following structure:
Order is not guaranteed!

object 1:

```
{
"outer": [
            {
                "inner": [
                    {
                        "Service1": 34,
                        "title": [
                            {
                                "level1": 57
                            },
                            {
                                "level2": 75
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

object 2:

```
{
"outer": [
            {
                "inner": [
                    {
                        "Service2": 23,
                        "title": [
                            {
                                "level1": 89
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "inner": [
                    {
                        "title": [
                            {
                                "level1": 45
                            }
                        ],
                        "Service1": 68
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

Wanted to find a generic way to compare both objects and add missing elements from object 2 to object 1 and from object 1 to object 2.

Missing elements can be at any level.

inner.service1 can be found in both objects but elements at title level can be different. I would like to add them back to other object but with empty or value with 0 for that key

```
  Object 2:

{
"outer": [
            {
                "inner": [
                    {
                        "Service2": 23,
                        "title": [
                            {
                                "level1": 89
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "inner": [
                    {
                        "title": [
                            {
                                "level1": 45
                            },
                             {
                                "level2": 
                            }
                        ],
                        "Service1": 68
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]

Object 1:

{
"outer": [
             {
                "inner": [
                    {
                        "Service2": ,
                        "title": [
                            {
                                "level1":
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "inner": [
                    {
                        "Service1": 34,
                        "title": [
                            {
                                "level1": 57
                            },
                            {
                                "level2": 75
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comparing and finding difference for simple json is easy but for nested I cannot think of a way to compare and add them back to each other.

Have went through other solutions but it wasn't working for me!
Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood, but If you want all the values from both, why not create a new object? Something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/syew40Lt/)

Comment: Missing element can be at lowest level. ex: one or more of the titles is missing and need to add the key with empty value to other